# Can I reuse an Animate object in cocos 2d-x for generated Sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm having a cocos2d-x game and inside i generate a `Sprite` that has a frame `Animate`. I don't want to create every time this animation so I've tried to make it globally and make `object->runAction('myGlobalAnimate')` but when a new object is created the frame animation stops from the previous `Sprite`. How can I use the same Animate to all my nodes (to make this game efficient and resources friendly)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that that you have to clone it
Like this:

```
object->runAction('myGlobalAnimate'->clone());
```

Give it a try,

Comment: i will try but it doesn't use same amount of resources to clone as if creating a new one? Because i'm interested to optimise the code

Comment: I don't see any more efficient way to do so. It's used even in the cocos2dx programmers guide. But i'm also a bit new to this so it wouldn't surprise me if i were wrong.

Comment: i will appreciate it if you'll respond positively  to my answer